# p:fileUpload update oncomplete not work .... in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, primefaces

In primefaces the update and onComplete of p:fileUpload doesn' t work in **IE10**. actually I want to display the name of my uploaded file under the component p:fileUpload "advanced". but now I try just to display an alert(); after uploading my file, it works on Firefox but not on IE10.
thanks.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:30%">
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload id="f1" mode="advanced"
            fileUploadListener="#{myController.handleFileUpload}"
            oncomplete="alert();" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jrxml)$/"
            update=":management:loaderPanel">
        </p:fileUpload>
    </h:form>
    <p:column style="text-align:left;width:20%">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{myController.fileName}" />
    </p:column>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: you mean it's not working in any mode i.e `standard mode` of IE10 or `Compitability mode` either?

Comment: Hi SRy, yes it's not working in both of them :(

Comment: Not sure , I tested and it's working for me. Can you show me your `onComplete` method.'

Comment: please find above the code